# Firefox not support font-face

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

Web font is not rendered properly in firefox. It working fine for Chrome browser.

Below is my CSS code,

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DINm';
    src: url('http://www.themediaverse.com.au/wp-content/themes/themediaverse/assets/fonts/DINWeb-Medium.eot');
    src: url('http://www.themediaverse.com.au/wp-content/themes/themediaverse/assets/fonts/DINWeb-Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
    src: url('http://www.themediaverse.com.au/wp-content/themes/themediaverse/assets/fonts/DINWeb-Medium.woff') format('woff');
    src: url('http://www.themediaverse.com.au/wp-content/themes/themediaverse/assets/fonts/DINComp-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

  }
```

I have referred below url,
[CSS Font-Face url not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104798/css-font-face-url-not-working)

How can i resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those links are to font files that don't allow cross-site linking.  Chrome doesn't follow that part of the specification, but Firefox does.

See the "published site" part https://stackoverflow.com/a/3704578/720912 for how to configure the server to allow linking to the fonts.

Comment: Thanks @Boris. I found that "bad URI or cross-site access not allowed" warning message from firebug. I have changed the value as false in security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy property (from the above link). but it does not works.

Comment: That preference only affects file:// URIs.  Again, you want the "published site" bit.

Answer (score 0):

change the code from

`format ('truetype');`

to

`format ('opentype');`

and this should work for you.

That was listed in the article referenced from the other page near the bottom and it worked for me. This fiddle shows the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Phlume/CMv8G/1/

You should see this:

[image]

The article also mentioned that for otf or ttf fonts you can leave the `format` section off entirely -- it is optional as the format is open type.

Comment: the above solution is not working for me. It will taking "courier" font as default. I have checked chrome browser too ...

Comment: Pls inspect the result of "Test 1...2...3.." in your firebug. This is "Courier" font.

Comment: yes.. it should be.. notice the universal reset tag `*{font-family:courier;}` this will set everything to courier that isn't defined elsewhere. Check your font file at that site for the ttf though... it is set as `DINComp-Medium` when all of the rest are set as `DINWeb-Medium` Perhaps the font wasn't set up properly... or can't be used on the web?